# How do I maximize my end-of-fight bonus?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

When you get an enemy down to 0 health, you're given a brief opportunity to attack for bonus experience. Combos don't seem to activate in this bonus mode. However, when I slash as fast as I can, I don't always get the same amount of bonus experience.

Is the bonus experience based on the number of attacks I complete? Is it based on the amount of damage I've dealt? Does technique make any difference, or is it all about speed and/or your attack attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of times you attack during the finishing combo does increase your bonus experience. You can also create combos in that mode, which give you more experience, but you attack a little slower.

Comment: I've never seen a combo work in that mode. Does it only happen with specific weapon types? Or does it just not show the usual "combo" text?

Comment: I've done it with dual wield weapons.

Comment: @sjohnston It doesn't show the combo text but you can perform any of them no matter the weapon type.